# Weird behaviour in App Engine when using simplejson.dumps in order to send a dictionary via django to javascript

Tags: django, json, google-app-engine

I'm sending via django all the texts of my site as a dictionary for the Javascript code to use. I'm also planting some of the values directly with the django.

```
a = gui_texts
```

This code

```
a['entireText'] = {}
a['entireText'] = json.dumps(gui_texts)
```

And this code

```
a['entireText'] = json.dumps(gui_texts)
```

Produce different results. The first one is fine. The second one results in recursive appearance of the dictionary inside itself whenever I refresh the page (it quickly becomes too big for the browser to handle).

This is the django line:

```
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, a))
```

And this is the javascript:

```
texts = {{entireText|safe}};
```

To me it is very strange and I would like to know what's going on. Is there some cache used by the django functions and/or the simplejson.dumps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are recursively adding `gui_texts` to itself by setting a to gui_texts and then modifying it.

```
>>> gui_texts = {}
>>> gui_texts
{}
>>> import json
>>> gui_texts['entireText'] = json.dumps(gui_texts)
>>> gui_texts
{'entireText': '{}'}
>>> gui_texts['entireText'] = json.dumps(gui_texts)
>>> gui_texts
{'entireText': '{"entireText": "{}"}'}
```

If you make `a = gui_texts`, don't add `gui_texts` to a/itself.

Setting entireText to {} before json dump will break the recursion, but should still be avoided. When you add gui_texts to itself, you have reset the entireText to empty dict instead of the previous serialization, which prevents it from growing.

```
>>> gui_texts = {}
>>> gui_texts['entireText'] = {}
>>> gui_texts
{'entireText': {}}
>>> gui_texts['entireText'] = json.dumps(gui_texts)
>>> gui_texts
{'entireText': '{"entireText": {}}'}
>>> gui_texts['entireText'] = {}
>>> gui_texts
{'entireText': {}}
>>> gui_texts['entireText'] = json.dumps(gui_texts)
>>> gui_texts
{'entireText': '{"entireText": {}}'}
```

You probably want to make a copy of gui_texts like `a = gui_texts.copy()` if gui_texts comes from code and you want to modify before displaying it

Module variables are shared between all threads, only thread local is local to a thread. You don't start a new interpreter with all imports etc for every page request. The ability to modify these can be very powerful, but might sometimes bite you if you don't fully understand what's going on.

Comment: That makes sense. But still, it doesn't explain why the two codes behave differently, does it? Also, it implies that there is interactions between thread since each get request is handled by a different thread no?

Comment: I tried elaborating on why they behave differently when you reset entireText before serializing gui_texts it into itself. Module variables and imports are shared between threads.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the value using HttpResponse

The example code will be

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(gui_texts), 'application/json')
```